# media queries in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, media-queries

I have the following css. It is working fine in Chrome and FireFox but not IE 11. 
I thought media queries worked in IE 11? How should I code it so it works for Internet Explorer? (I guess all versions would be good).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1025px){
div#DYKcontainer { width:26.5%; }
 }
  @media screen and (min-width: 1025px){    
div#DYKcontainer {     width:27.5%; } 
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: When the viewport is 1025px, both media queries will match. Which one will apply then? This is determined by source ordering, i.e. the one that is defined last will override properties that are also in the first ruleset. In your example, this doesn't matter as you are only setting the `width` property in each ruleset. But what if you defined a black background color in the first ruleset and a black font color in the second? At exactly 1025 px viewport width, you would have black text on black background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: 
[Do Media Queries work in MediaWiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593312/do-media-queries-work-in-mediawiki)

> Method 2:
>
> According to a response from a MediaWiki developer to this bug I filed:
>
> If you're in a skin and you want something to apply to a specific media type, put it in a separate file and declare the media type in the resource definition. Either that or omit the media type in the resource definition and you'll be able to use @media blocks.
>
> So, in resources/resources.php, in the skin's array constructor, replace this line:
>
> 'styles' => array( 'customskin/customstyle.css' => array( 'media' => 'screen' ) ),
>   With this line:
>
> 'styles' => array( 'customskin/customstyle.css' ),

Answer (score 0):

To make media queries work in IE, use [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). Download the script file, copy it to your scripts folder (or wherever you like). Then put the line below into the head part of your html document (assuming you copied the file to the scripts folder).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/respond.js"></script>
```

And that's it. IE will start to support media queries.

Comment: the link downloads a folder with quite a few files. I'm not sure which one I need? Should I include the whole folder or just Respond/src/respond.js?

Comment: @LTech Download script file only (respond.js)

Comment: PS: Make sure your max-width (or min-width) is not set as max-device-width (or min-device-width) as IE11 won't parse that and won't even work with respond.js !!

Comment: This script is meant only for IE6-8, isn't it? Because IE9+ do support media queries.

Comment: This doesn't help for complex cases when mediaquery overrides some other stile with !important.